# How do I set what port Eclipse uses for local help server?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to set what port Eclipse uses for its local help server (e.g. localhost:64219/help/index.jsp)? I would like to bookmark specific pages, but I obviously can't since the port changes each time it runs.

I personally think its crazy they don't just try a common port # and then work up from there so there is consistency not just for a given user, but across users. That would make it possible to share local help links with coworkers.

I found this [help article](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_infocenter.htm) on running a standalone Information Center that says you can -port, but that doesn't seem to work with Eclipse itself (I tried adding it to eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 1):

In current Kepler release it can be changed by adding

```
-vmargs
-Dserver_port=8089
```

in config.ini